Bootstrap 5.3.0 form checkboxes have different width
CSS
input[type='checkbox']
{
    transform: scale( 2 );
    margin-right: 1.5em;
}

Html
<div class="form-check d-flex align-items-center mb-3">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="mChk1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="mChk1">
        t urpt uwit urig ejgwugjmbnesiwhr wit pwi ho joid wptig wuweo
    </label>
</div>

<div class="form-check d-flex align-items-center mb-3">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="mChk2">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="mChk2">
        t urpt uwit urig ejgwugjmbnesiwhr wit pwi ho joid wptig wuweo owugwkvn wptewuglbwgutw nbwp riweupriu eoriwei wruwe oruweknwprfeoi uwepowpeoi urwepoiw epoif wpeihwephpo nwpwhfwepoio wieru eiurewpir f powg
    </label>
</div>


Why??


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    input[type='checkbox'] {
      transform: scale( 2);
      margin-right: 1.5em;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="p-3 m-0 border-0 bd-example m-0 border-0">



  <div class="form-check d-flex align-items-center mb-3">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="mChk1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="mChk1">
          t urpt uwit urig ejgwugjmbnesiwhr wit pwi ho joid wptig wuweo
      </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-check d-flex align-items-center mb-3">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="mChk2">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="mChk2">
          t urpt uwit urig ejgwugjmbnesiwhr wit pwi ho joid wptig wuweo owugwkvn wptewuglbwgutw nbwp riweupriu eoriwei wruwe oruweknwprfeoi uwepowpeoi urwepoiw epoif wpeihwephpo nwpwhfwepoio wieru eiurewpir f powg
      </label>
  </div>


</body>

</html>




I've created a snippet from your code, and as you can see, it doesn't show like on your screenshot.. you should probably debug and see if there's another style or similar (for example, black border)

Thanks @traynor Bootstrap 5.3.3 fixed the problem. It only exhibits in 5.3.0.

It seems that in BS v5.3.0 checkbox shrinks in flexbox container (in your case it shows in the second checkbox, because there is more text filling the container, causing the shrink):


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    input[type='checkbox'] {
      transform: scale( 2);
      margin-right: 1.5em;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="p-3 m-0 border-0 bd-example m-0 border-0">



  <div class="form-check d-flex align-items-center mb-3">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="mChk1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="mChk1">
          t urpt uwit urig ejgwugjmbnesiwhr wit pwi ho joid wptig wuweo
      </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-check d-flex align-items-center mb-3">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="mChk2">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="mChk2">
          t urpt uwit urig ejgwugjmbnesiwhr wit pwi ho joid wptig wuweo owugwkvn wptewuglbwgutw nbwp riweupriu eoriwei wruwe oruweknwprfeoi uwepowpeoi urwepoiw epoif wpeihwephpo nwpwhfwepoio wieru eiurewpir f powg
      </label>
  </div>


</body>

</html>



Adding flex-shrink: 0; to checkbox tag seems to prevent that:
    input[type='checkbox'] {
      transform: scale( 2);
      margin-right: 1.5em;
      flex-shrink: 0;
    }



<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    input[type='checkbox'] {
      transform: scale( 2);
      margin-right: 1.5em;
      flex-shrink: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="p-3 m-0 border-0 bd-example m-0 border-0">



  <div class="form-check d-flex align-items-center mb-3">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="mChk1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="mChk1">
          t urpt uwit urig ejgwugjmbnesiwhr wit pwi ho joid wptig wuweo
      </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-check d-flex align-items-center mb-3">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="mChk2">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="mChk2">
          t urpt uwit urig ejgwugjmbnesiwhr wit pwi ho joid wptig wuweo owugwkvn wptewuglbwgutw nbwp riweupriu eoriwei wruwe oruweknwprfeoi uwepowpeoi urwepoiw epoif wpeihwephpo nwpwhfwepoio wieru eiurewpir f powg
      </label>
  </div>


</body>

</html>



It seems to be fixed in BS ^5.3.2
